# route via default gateway of the interface

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route

I have a `gRPC client` (works on top of `HTTP2`). I want to route the connection via different interfaces at different times. I generally create an instance of the client and set a route to force gRPC to use a particular interface (by resolving hostname and executing `ip route add` commands) and then I connect to the client hoping it will be routed via particular interface (eth0 or wlan0).

However, it is not working.

I tired following commands

```
# To Route via WiFi
ip route del A.B.C.D
ip route add A.B.C.D dev wlan0

# To Route via Ethernet
ip route del A.B.C.D
ip route add A.B.C.D dev eth0
```

However, this works for me,

```
# To Route via WiFi
ip route del A.B.C.D
ip route add A.B.C.D dev wlan0 via GATEWAY_IP_ADDR
```

I don't want to use Gateway's IP address in my scripts as I will to update the script if my device connects to different WiFi or Ethernet Network.

Please help. I am looking for something which could automatically route the connection via the default gateway of the interface.

Comment: Even your default route requires the use of "via gateway". What makes you think it's optional? It's needed for link layer address resolution (layer 3 IPv4 to layer 2 Ethernet MAC, using ARP). You can have your script use the correct value.

Comment: How can I get a gateway for a interface? What if a interface is `ppp`?

Comment: Well ppp is layer 3 and doesn't really need a gateway, since there's no link layer address resolution needed. about the 1st question in the comment: when you type "ip route", don't you get the gateway?

Comment: I need to parse it then using `awk`. I was thinking about something `ip route add A.B.C.D via default dev eth0`. Looks like it is not possible. I thought may be `ip` will automatically figure out gateway depending upon the interface passed.

Comment: `ip` has a json output that can be parsed by `jq`. Anyway I realize that only you can know what interface to use at a given time.